# How to set the maximum date in MDDatePicker in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am Setting Maximum date but not able to disable Remaining date 
Example like - Date of Birth Selection.

Any one has idea about that.
thanks in Advance.
[image]

Comment: did you find a solution please?

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void) dateTextField:(id)sender
{
    UIDatePicker *picker = (UIDatePicker*) dateOfBirthField.inputView;
   // [picker setMaximumDate:[NSDate date]];
    [picker setMinimumDate:[NSDate date]];

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    NSDate *eventDate = picker.date;
   [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy/MM/dd"];

   NSString *dateString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:eventDate];
   dateOfBirthField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",dateString];
}
```

Comment: I am Using MDDatePicker Third Party Library not UIDatePicker.

Comment: Where you are setting Minimum date. Follow that method or property and search in the library for max date

Answer (score 0):

`MDDatePickerDialog` class uses `MDCalendar` to manage its minimum date. If you will look at the implementation of `MDCalendar` you will find following implementation in `initialize` method:

```
_maximumDate = [NSDateHelper mdDateWithYear:2037 month:12 day:31];
```

First try setting this date to  a static value of your choice to see this is the required variable, then you can move this property declaration to header file of `MDCalendar` to make this `maximumDate` variable accessible outside the class. As a next step you can make a property in `MDDatePickerDialog` to set maximum date in the same way it sets minimum date.

A part from `MDDatePicker.m` file

```
- (void)setMinimumDate:(NSDate *)minimumDate {
    self.calendar.minimumDate = minimumDate;
}
```

*P.S. Remember to handle the date validations like date should be valid and maximum date should not be earlier than minimum date etc.*

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

You just have to add date whatever you want to make maximum, here I have to make only a week date should be selected from the current date, So here is the code which I've written, where you show the date picker just add one line:

```
- _datePicker.maximumDate = [[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval:60*60*24*7]; ;
```

After that search this method into MDCalender.m file and replace with this code.

```
- (BOOL)shouldSelectDate:(NSDate *)date {
    BOOL result;
    if ([self.maximumDate timeIntervalSince1970] >= date.timeIntervalSince1970 ) {
        result =
        (date.timeIntervalSince1970 >= self.minimumDate.timeIntervalSince1970);
        return result;
    }
    return result;
}
```

It worked for me. Thanks